# change localhorst (jenkins url)

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

im trying to trigger a webhook from github to my local Jenkins but it needs another jekins URL instead of the localhost:8080/ .
How can I change my jenkins URL please and how to find the valid hostname? I tried serveo.net  but the url is still the same.

Comment: You want to create a domain and make Jenkins use that domain so that GitHub can access it? Maybe an easier option is to do it the other way around and have Jenkins poll GitHub so that the build gets triggered?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ngrok** to expose the port **jenkins** is using and make it accessible, then use the url provided by **ngrok** to setup the **Github** webhook by adding *github-webhook* at the end of the url.

you can follow the first part of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HHIKzIHww8) for better understanding!